# Dynamic conditions generator in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have developed modules according to the business requirements. Now, what I need is a dynamic condition generator or query generator. So, for example, consider the below case:

```
B1 = spark.sql("select * from xyz where ABC <> DEF and CONDITIONS1 or CONDITIONS2 or CONDITIONS3")
```

I have many and different business logic as above. So, in this case, I identified a common pattern like `"select *"` and I created a property file with `.properties` extension and I read that variable inside the `.py` file:

`Key-Value` pair in properties file:

```
selectVar = "Select * from "
```

But, now what demand is needed to create a way or interface where user can modify the conditions as per their need. Like they can add multiple conditions or remove a condition. In the above example they can remove `CONDITIONS2` or add `CONDITIONS4` or they can change the `CONDITIONS3` as per their need. It should be dynamic. No, coding part should be required on client-side. They just want to pass conditions and it should be substituted in the query and it should execute accordingly. So, how can I do it in pyspark. I tried searching for available tools in this case but, no luck. Can anyone help me with the approach?

Comment: maintain a list of conditions `[cond1, cond2, cond3]` and join them `" or ".join(cond_list)`?

Comment: can you elaborate it in detail? maybe as an answer. unable to understand

Answer (score 0):

It is non-trivial to write a generic interface that parses every type of expression. However for the specific case of multiple filter expressions you can do something like this:

```
def customExprEval(df: DataFrame, expr: String*): DataFrame = {
    expr.foldLeft(df){(d, i) => d.where(i)}
}
```

You can now call this function with variable number of conditional expressions:

```
val B1 = spark.sql("select * from xyz")
val B2 = customExprEval(B1,  "ABC <> DEF", "CONDITIONS1 or CONDITIONS2 or CONDITIONS3")  
val B3 = customExprEval(B1, "ABC <> DEF")
```

Comment: Thanks for your helo. But, user needs to pass the conditions somewhere and it should be passed in this code automatically. Is there any UI based rule engine which can be integrated with pyspark?since the user doesn't want to touch the code.

Comment: Also, can we integrate DROOLS with pyspark?

Comment: Could you help me with my doubs @Gsquare